# How to convert continuous data into categorical using bins based on column minimum and maximum value in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, continuous, bins

I am trying to bins the data based on the minimum and maximum values of all columns. I am facing a problem I am doing manually. I want to do it automatically by just passing my CSV file data. The shape of my data is (363667,60). I am showing the Sample of my dataset.

```
Sno     Col1              col2            col3            col4          col5    
1      84.548913         1.972093         53475.298      63982.83     77064.641304
2      72.036364         5.741337         44580.824      49533.727    71510.181818 
3      15.820000         1.239958         5562.0950      7355.3950    7283.725000
4      26.465409         2.206942         11060.185      12358.4829   16324.478049 
5      239.393443        2.521642         166275.295     214985.754   220683.901639
6      88.474903         1.09879          49609.6409     54794.0424   78830.223938
7      32.766234         1.007994         16966.6147     19215.6753   28802.948052 
8      79.096685         7.605093         39728.3121     47221.88950  71375.127072
9      344.000000        5.440523         225168.904     267927.3714  317527.742857
10     22.459016         1.884006         14640.9180     15854.91803  20288.557377
```

I am using the following code for each column.

```
df=pd.read_csv("Oversampling-Balanced.csv", low_memory=False, na_values='?')
bins1=[-0.001,228.0,493.051,812.0,1292.0,10368.5]
# # #name of the groups
gr_names1=['Very_Low','Low','Medium','High','Very_High']
df['lx_pmu_p1fwm_engine_speed_torque_h_x_index_1']=pd.cut(df["lx_pmu_p1fwm_engine_speed_torque_h_x_index_1"],bins1,labels=gr_names1)
```

I want to do this for all columns not manually. I want to do this task with less code by just passing the data frame of the CSV file.

Desired Output is:

```
Sno     Col1       col2            col3       col4          col5    
1      low         low         low           low          low
2      low         high        very_low      very_low     low
3      very_low    very_low    very_low      very_low     very_low
4      very_low    low         very_low      very_low     very_low 
5      high        low         high          very_high    High
6      low         very_low    low           low          low
7      very_low    very_low    very_low      very_low     very_low 
8      low         very_high   very_low      very_low     low
9      very_high   high        very_high     very_high    very_high
10     very_low    low         very_low      very_low     very_low
```

Comment: You can use `df.apply`

Comment: @DivyanshuSrivastava but how to do that for all columns at the same time. I don't know exactly how to code it for condition minimum and maximum value

Comment: @Anki Can you show your expected output?

Comment: How did you calculate the bin values manually?

Comment: @ChrisSears I Calculate the Maximum value of a column and divided it with numbers of bins I want to make.

Comment: If you want the the bins to be equally spaced in the column values, just pass an int (e.g., `bins=5`) instead of the bin values, and let pandas do the work for you. From [the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) "bins: int : Defines the number of equal-width bins in the range of x. The range of x is extended by .1% on each side to include the minimum and maximum values of x."

Comment: @ G. Anderson I am new to python. Can you help me to code it

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`df.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) to apply a custom `categorize` function on each column, then you can use [`np.linespace`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html) to divide the column max value in evenly spaced intervals. Use:

```
import numpy as np

def categorize(col):
    bins = np.linspace(0, col.max(), 6)
    return pd.cut(col, bins, labels=['Very_Low','Low','Medium','High','Very_High'])

df = df.apply(categorize)
print(df)
```

This prints:

```
         Col1       col2       col3       col4       col5
Sno                                                       
1          Low        Low        Low        Low        Low
2          Low       High   Very_Low   Very_Low        Low
3     Very_Low   Very_Low   Very_Low   Very_Low   Very_Low
4     Very_Low        Low   Very_Low   Very_Low   Very_Low
5         High        Low       High  Very_High       High
6          Low   Very_Low        Low        Low        Low
7     Very_Low   Very_Low   Very_Low   Very_Low   Very_Low
8          Low  Very_High   Very_Low   Very_Low        Low
9    Very_High       High  Very_High  Very_High  Very_High
10    Very_Low        Low   Very_Low   Very_Low   Very_Low
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. but this is for one column that's what am doing. But I want to do all the columns in my data frame

Comment: @Anki As per the conversation on the mail, i have updated the answer.

Comment: @shubahm Sharma thank you for the solution. code is working perfectly. But now getting Nan values. it taking all zero values as NAN.

Answer (score 0):

As @G Anderson mentioned, `cut` will calculate the bin ranges automatically if you specify the number of bins. I would actually recommend `qcut` over regular `cut` so the bin ranges are based on quantiles.

Here's an example of adding a 'bin' column for each data column:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = np.array(
    [[1, 10.0, 1000.0], 
     [2, 20.0, 0.2],
     [3, 30.0, 300.0],
     [4, 40.0, 0.04],
     [5, 50.0, 50.0],
     [6, 60.0, 0.006],
     [7, 70.0, 7.0],
     [8, 80.0, 0.0008],
     [9, 90.0, 9000000],
     ])

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=["id", "col1", "col2"])

for col in df.columns[1:]:
  df[col+'_bin'] = pd.qcut(df[col], 5, ['Very_Low','Low','Medium','High','Very_High'])
```

Output:

```
    id  col1         col2   col1_bin   col2_bin
0  1.0  10.0  1.00000e+03   Very_Low  Very_High
1  2.0  20.0  2.00000e-01   Very_Low        Low
2  3.0  30.0  3.00000e+02        Low       High
3  4.0  40.0  4.00000e-02        Low        Low
4  5.0  50.0  5.00000e+01     Medium       High
5  6.0  60.0  6.00000e-03       High   Very_Low
6  7.0  70.0  7.00000e+00       High     Medium
7  8.0  80.0  8.00000e-04  Very_High   Very_Low
8  9.0  90.0  9.00000e+06  Very_High  Very_High
```

Comment: I am getting error because don't have unique values in the column.ValueError: Bin edges must be unique: array([    0. ,  6099.6,  7999. ,  7999. ,  7999. , 28778. ]).
You can drop duplicate edges by setting the 'duplicates' kwarg

Comment: can you please suggest to me what to do solve this error

Comment: Try adding `, duplicates='drop'` as the last argument to `qcut()`

Comment: can you tell how to give the range from col.min(), col.max() for column value to make bins

Comment: @Anki, `qcut()` and `cut()` automatically calculate the bin ranges based on the min and max, so you don't have to write that code. With `qcut()` it also looks at the distribution of data to calculate quantiles. Generally you should let Pandas do things for you when possible, because it will be faster and less error prone.

Comment: @ Chris Sears Thanks